# Комбинаторика из Unicode, как сделать?

Tags: javascript, комбинаторика

Есть такой код:

```js
function  generate() {
 document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
      const numbers = (new Array(25)).fill(1).map((a, i) => a + i);
      let resultSet = new Map();
      while (resultSet.size < 1000) {
        let nums = shuffle(numbers).slice(0, 5);
        let key = (nums.sort() + '');
        resultSet.set(key, nums);
      }
      resultSet.forEach(val => {
        const main = createTableWithContent(val.join('-'), "one");
        const additional = createTableWithContent(randInt(), "two");
        main.append(additional);
        document.getElementById("myTable").append(main);
      })
    }
    
    function shuffle(arr) {
      return arr.map(el => {
        return {
          item: el,
          sort: Math.random()
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort).map(el => el.item);
    }
    
    function randInt(min = 1, max = 4) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    
    function createTableWithContent(content, className) {
      const tableEl = document.createElement("TABLE");
      tableEl.className = className || "";
      tableEl.append(content);
      return tableEl;
      
    }
```

```html
<input class="annoying-btn" type="button" value="Получить комбинацию" onclick="generate()" />
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

Как переделать код так, чтобы вместо чисел составлялись комбинации из unicode символов из этого раздела:

```
https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/playing-cards/
```

Не понимаю, как сделать массив генерированных Unicode символов.

Comment: уточните: могут ли повторятся картинки в одной комбинации; могут ли повторятся сами комбинации. Для отвечающих это важно.

Comment: @UModeL Нет, важно чтобы картинки в одной комбинации не повторялись, в пределах 1000 комбинаций повторений так же не должно быть, после нового генерирования прошлая повторная комбинация возможна.

Comment: @UModeL подправил вопрос.

Comment: Подозреваю, что для открытия может немного не дотянуть. Дополните вопрос - с чем конкретно сейчас у вас затруднения.

Comment: @0xdb Не знаю как сделать массив, чтоб генерировались Unicode символы.

Answer (score 0):

Существует `N = С(52, 8) = 752538150` комбинаций карт.

Можно сгенерировать 1000 неповторяющихся случайных чисел в этом диапазоне и сопоставить каждому числу комбинацию.

В данном случае количество комбинаций очень мало по сравнению с диапазоном, поэтому можно не заморачиваться с хитрыми подходами, а просто проверять, есть ли уже такое число в наборе (map) сгенерированных.

Пусть комбинация представлена 64-битным числом. Тогда один набор можно сгенерировать, проверяя, что очередной генерируемый случайный бит не совпадает с уже имеющимся, пока не наберётся 8 установленных битов (выбрано 8 карт).
А комбинация записывается в мап с проверкой, не было ли ещё такой, пока не наберётся 1000 комбинаций

пример на Python с уменьшенными числами (в комментах - что должно быть):

```
import random
combs = {}
while len(combs) < 10:  #1000
    cardset = 0
    cnt = 0
    while cnt < 4:      #8
        r = 1 << random.randrange(8)  # 52
        if (cardset & r) == 0:
            cardset = cardset | r
            cnt += 1
    if not(cardset in combs):
        combs[cardset] = 0
for x in combs:
    print(bin(x))

 0b1101100
 0b11101
 0b1001101
 0b1011010
 0b110011
 0b10111
 0b110101
 0b10001101
 0b10001011
 0b10101001
```

Comment: Вы правы, но как это реализовать? Как это сделать?

Comment: Что именно сделать не получается?

Comment: Не знаю как реализовать это

Comment: Проблема разбивается на несколько подзадач. Их нужно решать поочерёдно. За Вас никто этого не сделает (обратите внимание на причину закрытия вопроса).

Comment: Спасибо за правильное замечание, я исправил выше

Comment: Привел пример реализации

Comment: За это спасибо,но как в JS?

Comment: Я принцип показал в работе, а как на JS это лучше сделать - не знаю.